# How much exercise should a pregnant woman do?

Tags: pregnancy

It's in most people's knowledge that pregnant women should generally not exercise due to the risk of harming the baby with prolonged and strenuous work-outs.

If one was pregnant, but still wanted to exercise for her health - how much exercise is safe? At what times is it safe to exercise while pregnant?

Comment: I'm not actually sure, but perhaps this could go in the [Pregnancy and Child Birth proposition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48405/pregnancy-and-child-birth?referrer=wdDPL3685XEXgZDFSjWKdA2). I'd like to hear some opinions on it C:

Comment: As a wrong answer might be dangerous for both mother and child I am highly skeptical about this question. It _could_ count as _injury prevention_ but actually I would count it as a general health question which would be off topic.

Comment: I think this also depends on your personal fitness and the kind of stuff you do. I had a friend who did a lot of yoga who continued to practice until right before the birth. (She would stand on her head at eight months pregnant which she found very comfortable). But if you've never done yoga, you may find it a bit of a strain.

Comment: Another angle to the question might be - is there any proof that it's NOT safe for pregnant women to exercise, or do certain types of exercise, or things they shouldn't begin if they aren't used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My wife and I just had a baby.  Her OBGYN told her (remember everyone is different) it was based off of how active she was before hand.  Since she went to the gym 5-6 days a week, she continued to exercise and go to Zumba classes until 1 week before he was born.  She did have to leave class to pee more as the baby tap-danced on her bladder though.  Talk to your doctors and figure out a plan that is right for you!